# looking for android pattern unlock

Tags: android, shell

I forgot my android pattern, for which i don't want to do factory reset n loose my data, pics n other stuffs.

Unfortunately, my mobile data or wifi is also not enabled, which could help me to login with my google account and i have reset it.

My study shows me that, i need to remove gesture.key file, for which through android sdk i already tried below command:

**adb shell rm /data/system/gesture.key**

but i got permission denied as result.

second, i tried to enable wifi or data network, but again no result since android which i am using is rooted. Because of permission denied , i couldnt able to perform anything.

Please suggest if you know how to get it resolve without data loss.Appreciate your responses.

Comment: my android phone is not having CWM recovery mode, and i cant install it also as it is locked, another, i tried to download and install Aroma File Manager through sd card option in recovery but that option i am not getting in my asus zenfone 5. so, if you can tell me how to do it without root permission, or any other way which you know, that will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you cant remove pattern files without root permission,just need root permission or install custom recovery.
if USB debug enabled you can root.
use this links for root
[(root-asus-zenfone-5-kitkat-4-4-2)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/zenfone-5/general/root-asus-zenfone-5-kitkat-4-4-2-100-t2947092)
and
[root-asus-zenfone-5-lollipop-5.0](http://redirect.viglink.com/?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_147604792795814&key=f0a7f91912ae2b52e0700f73990eb321&libId=iu34pt3601000n4o000DAc0ts96u3&loc=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.xda-developers.com%2Fandroid%2Fgeneral%2Fasus-zenfone-5-lollipop-root-t3135056&v=1&out=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Ffile%2Fd%2F0B9OM9nJbQarYZVRKM09sa21jOW8%2Fview&ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&title=Asus%20Zenfone%205%20Ultimate%20Guide%3AROOT%2CROM%2CTWEAK%E2%80%A6%20%7C%20Android%20Development%20and%20Hacking&txt=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Ffile%2Fd%2F0B9O...9sa21jOW8%2Fview)

Comment: thanks for your response, will i lose all my data, if root it?

Comment: with these methods you dont loose any data.